# python regular_expression_ multiple expression within expression

Tags: python

In my python script  it needed a expression like

```
"\[.*[ERROR].*\n.*\n.*\n.*/\n.*is for multiple time/[\]]{2}"
```

please let me know how to take `"\n."` for  multiple time... I'm getting stuck in this place

Answer (score 0):

There is the **multiline** flag available, that let's you match across multiple lines.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE

> re.**MULTILINE**
>
> When specified, the pattern character '^' matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character '$' matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each newline). By default, '^' matches only at the beginning of the string, and '$' only at the end of the string and immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string.

You also have access to **DOTALL** that will have **.** match even newlines

> re.**DOTALL**
>
> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.

Depending on your match, those two flags let you choose how newlines are handled. In your case, you probably want to adjust your pattern like this:

```
text = '\n[ [ERROR]\n\nsome text\nis for multiple time]'
re.findall("\[.*\[ERROR\].*is for multiple time\]", text, re.DOTALL)
# result: ['[ [ERROR]\n\nsome text\nis for multiple time]']
```

Comment: Actually its giving the wrong output.. Since first " .*  "  itself taking as **re.DOTALL** and giving the complete string but I want the last " .* " many times takes as \n as well